# Find stripped e-mail in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

I want to prevent users from using the *same* e-mail multiple times. Many servers, however, are configured in a way that e-mails to `john.doe@example.com` would go in the same inbox as `j.oh.ndoe..@exmaple.com` or `johndoe+abc123@example.com`. Therefore, I applied a simple **PHP** function to *strip* an e-mail from its dots and ignore anything that's after a `+` sign.
Here is the **PHP** function I am using:

```php
function strip_email ($email) {
    $id = explode("@", $email)[0]; //what is before the '@'
    $noplus = explode("+", $id)[0]; //what is before the '+'
    $nodots = str_replace(".", "", $noplus); //and with dots removed
    return $nodots. "@" .$provider;
}
```

However, I would like to register users with the exact e-mail they have provided (not stripped). E.g., if the user has entered `john.doe+demo@example.com` I use this e-mail for the MySQL record as this is where the user wants to be reached (for instance some servers use the string after `+` to label e-mails or put them in different folders).

Upon **new registrations**, I am checking whether the e-mail exists in the following way:

```php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$query = "SELECT e-mail FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row) ... #email already in use
```

**The issue** is if the user has entered `john..doe+mylabel@example.com` that won't match any entry in the database, neither would it if the search value is stripped (`johndoe@example.com`).

Should I create a second row in my table and store as well the stripped e-mail?

Comment: You need to implement prepared statements with placeholders for security and stability.

Comment: How do you **know** that this sanitizing process will not have a negative impact? What if a new, legitimate user's email is "similar" to an existing email in your system.  This feels like an inadvisable path to go down.  I foresee this being an irritation to your visitors and an unreliable technique for you.

Comment: You should only explode the email string once and access its two parts, not `$provider = explode("@", $email)[1];` then `$id = explode("@", $email)[0];`

Comment: @mickmackusa The chance that `john.d@gmail.com` is the same person as `johnd@gmail.com` is extremely high. Specifically for Gmail, it is 100% as Gmail would consider both identical upon registration. I want to present an extra challenge to those who register with an *alias* e-mail to obtain a free trial.

Comment: @mickmackusa I was using the `$provider` for some additional DNS MX validation. You are totally correct it is unnecessary here.

Comment: Don't fight this. People always find a way. I have 5 aliases for one mailbox on outlook, none of them looks anything like the other.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, indeed, you can always create a new e-mail or find a disposable e-mail provider that has not been blacklisted, but that is some extra effort that may cause people to give up and not bother, but it is okay for me if *some* people still do that.

Comment: Better have a email confirmation option, to ensure those are valid emails. Then allow them to use the trial version. Generate a one time confirmation link and send it to user .

Comment: @Senthil I do require e-mails be verified by sending a token.

Comment: Since it's trickier to do the sanitising in MySQL than PHP, it would probably be easier to add another *column* to your table which contains the sanitised email, and compare on that e.g. `SELECT e-mail FROM users WHERE sanitised-email='$email' LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Note you can simplify your `explode` code with `list` i.e. `list($id, $provider) = explode('@', $email);`

Comment: Sites that do things like this are sites I don't bother with.  Also, it's *wild* that you're concerned about this sort of security, meanwhile you let anyone hijack your whole database via SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You should store both the original email and the "stripped" email in a single row in the table.

And then declare a unique constraint on the stripped version, so you do not get duplicates in that column.

Because you are doing the cleaning in PHP, you can pass in both versions of the email when you insert (or update) a new record.